# Regular expressions and intersection of groups

Tags: python, regex

I need to implement a substitution using regexps to add a space after dot only if it is not between two digits.

```
a.a -> a. a
7.7 -> 7.7
```

To implement it I have several rules and here is one of them:

```
text = (re.compile(u'(\D)(\.)(\D)')).sub('\\1\\2 \\3', text)
```

I expect to replace add spaces after dots between non-digit symbols, but for input

```
a.b.c.d.e
```

the result is

```
a. b.c. d.e
```

so there is no space between some symbols. Looks like 'a.b' is matched first and after it 'b' is not processed as a part of 'b.c.d'. Is it possible to fix this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use lookahead/lookbehind assertions

Comment: what should happen for `hello world.`? Do you mean a period anywhere or between tow non digit characters specifically?

Comment: There is a problem though. If you only want to exclude `digit-dot-digit` then your regex won't match `digit-dot-notdigit` or `notdigit-dot-digit`.

Comment: I'm sure if you include all the rules, you'd get a better regex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match the overlapping strings. You can use a [*lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) base regex in order to make it matches the overlapped strings too:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(u'(?<=\D)(\.)(?=\D)')
>>> 
>>> regex.sub(r'\1 ', "a.b.c.d.e")
'a. b. c. d. e'
```

Comment: I don't understand, OP literally says this is expected result `a. b.c. d.e`, Not this `a. b. c. d. e`

Comment: @Shafizadeh, that is the output they don't want, i.e what they are currently getting.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh .. I see. Thx for heads up.